# Java basic concurrent communicator - does not fully accept connection

Tags: java, sockets, concurrency

I want to create simple communicator with one server and few clients who could connect and send data to it. It works fine without any threads, with only one client, but once i try to incorporate concurrency it doesn't work. From client perspective there is some connection, I can send data, but there is no sign of receiving that data on server. Here is the server class:

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.InetAddress;
    import java.net.ServerSocket;
    import java.net.Socket;
    import java.util.Random;


    public class MyServerSocket implements Runnable
    {
        private ServerSocket serverSocket;

        public MyServerSocket() throws Exception
        {
            Random generator = new Random();
            this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(generator.nextInt(65000 - 60000) + 60000, 50, InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.105"));
        }


        public InetAddress getSocketIPAddress()
        {
            return this.serverSocket.getInetAddress();
        }

        public int getPort()
        {
            return this.serverSocket.getLocalPort();
        }

        public void run()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                System.out.println("Running a thread");
                try
                {
                    String data = null;
                    Socket client = this.serverSocket.accept();
                    String clientAddress = client.getInetAddress().getHostName();
                    System.out.println("Connection from: " + clientAddress);

                    System.out.println("Here I am");
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()));
                    String message = "";
                    while ((data = in.readLine()) != null && data.compareToIgnoreCase("quit") != 0)
                    {
                        message = ("\r\nMessage from " + clientAddress + ": " + data);
                        System.out.println(message);
                        out.write(message);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Something went wrong");
                } finally
                {
                    try
                    {
                        serverSocket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }


        }
    }
```

Server main:

```
import java.lang.Thread;
public class Main 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            MyServerSocket socket = new MyServerSocket();
            Runnable runnable = new MyServerSocket();
            System.out.println("Port number: " + socket.getPort() + " IP address: " + socket.getSocketIPAddress());
            Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
            thread.start();
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Client class:

```
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.net.InetAddress;
    import java.net.Socket;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class ClientSocket
    {
        private Socket socket;
        private Scanner scanner;

        ClientSocket(InetAddress serverAddress, int serverPort) throws Exception
        {
            this.socket = new Socket(serverAddress, serverPort);
            this.scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        }

        public void sendData() throws Exception
        {
            String data;
            System.out.println("Please type in the message. If you want to terminate the connection, type Quit");
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(this.socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            do
            {
                data = scanner.nextLine();
                out.println(data);
                out.flush();
            }while(data.compareToIgnoreCase("quit") != 0);
            out.println();
        }
    }
```

Client main:

```
    import java.net.InetAddress;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Main
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            int port;
            System.out.println("Provide port at which you will communicate with the server");
            port = scanner.nextInt();

            try
            {
            ClientSocket socket1 = new ClientSocket(InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.105"), port);
            socket1.sendData();

            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Could not connect to the server.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Server somehow stops its working when is about to accept the client connection, while client works fine and seem to be connected to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In server side, once you accept a client connection, you should new a thread to process this connection:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Random;


public class MyServerSocket implements Runnable {
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;

    public MyServerSocket() throws Exception {
        Random generator = new Random();
        this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(generator.nextInt(65000 - 60000) + 60000, 50, InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.105"));
    }


    public InetAddress getSocketIPAddress() {
        return this.serverSocket.getInetAddress();
    }

    public int getPort() {
        return this.serverSocket.getLocalPort();
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Running a thread");
            try(Socket client = this.serverSocket.accept()) {

                // new thread to process this client
                new Thread(() -> {
                    try {
                        String data = null;
                        String clientAddress = client.getInetAddress().getHostName();
                        System.out.println("Connection from: " + clientAddress);

                        System.out.println("Here I am");
                        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()));
                        String message = "";
                        while (true) {
                            if (!((data = in.readLine()) != null && data.compareToIgnoreCase("quit") != 0)) break;
                            message = ("\r\nMessage from " + clientAddress + ": " + data);
                            System.out.println(message);
                            out.write(message);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        System.out.println("Something went wrong");
                    } 
                }).start();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Something went wrong");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Stil the same output.

Comment: @SzK Sorry, I forget to remove your `finally` fragment, you shouldn't close serverSocket after accept client connection. I have update code, you can try my new code fragment.

Comment: @SzK You never show what program outputs. I can only guess your intention, I think my server side code is alright.

Comment: @Szk You can try to modify your Main as your follow self-answering. You run a thread with `start` and main thread immediately exit, you server program never really completely start. Not the problem of my server side code, try resources is all right, it only close a connection with one special client

Comment: Everything was good about server class - problem was with main class. Finally everything works, thank for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, somehow I solved that problem, but still I need to understand how does it work:

1. Accepting connection inside try block, without finally block (nor try with resources) so socket is opened all the time.
2. Modified main method so there is no threads or runnable objects at all in it. The whole process is done within the class:

Code:

```
public class Main 
{
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                MyServerSocket socket = new MyServerSocket();
                System.out.println("Port number: " + socket.getPort() + " IP address: " + socket.getSocketIPAddress());
                socket.run();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

If anyone could point me out mistakes that are still in this final version of code I'll be grateful.